# Skipped loading symbols & Cannot find or open the PDB file. Output at Debugging windows 8 app

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-8

When i Debug my windows phone App on Device, i get a long list of weird output continuously, but the app open and works fine except that some data is missing. What does this mean?

Here just few samples:

> 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs{B55E53A8-10BC-47A6-9657-A43A8F9E301E}\Install\BundleMobile2.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs{B55E53A8-10BC-47A6-9657-A43A8F9E301E}\Install\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Threading.Tasks.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs{B55E53A8-10BC-47A6-9657-A43A8F9E301E}\Install\System.Net.Http.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs{B55E53A8-10BC-47A6-9657-A43A8F9E301E}\Install\Newtonsoft.Json.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

Another sample:

> 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs{B55E53A8-10BC-47A6-9657-A43A8F9E301E}\Install\Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs{B55E53A8-10BC-47A6-9657-A43A8F9E301E}\Install\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs{B55E53A8-10BC-47A6-9657-A43A8F9E301E}\Install\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs{B55E53A8-10BC-47A6-9657-A43A8F9E301E}\Install\Microsoft.Phone.Toolkit.Testing.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs{B55E53A8-10BC-47A6-9657-A43A8F9E301E}\Install\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs{B55E53A8-10BC-47A6-9657-A43A8F9E301E}\Install\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Phone.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs{B55E53A8-10BC-47A6-9657-A43A8F9E301E}\Install\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTesting.Phone.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs{B55E53A8-10BC-47A6-9657-A43A8F9E301E}\Install\Sqlite.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.

Comment: That is normal, Visual Studio simply logs that it is unable to find debugging symbols for certain assemblies which is fine if you don't want to step through that code.

Comment: I have no solution for you (I have similar issues), but while debugging you can go to menu Debug->Windows->Modules to get details about loaded modules.

Comment: @ToniPetrina How can I determine whether a message like this is normal or not? Is there a list somewhere with all the normal stuff that I can safely ignore?

Comment: Not really, you have to "learn" from the experience. Install VSColorOutput extension, it will color real errors red in the output window.